# How to use Q.all() with complex array of promises?

Tags: node.js, q

Consider I have an array of objects and promises, something like:

```
[{
    a: 1
}, {
    a: 4
}, {
    a: 4
}, {
    promiseSend: [Function],
    valueOf: [Function]
}, {
    promiseSend: [Function],
    valueOf: [Function]
}]
```

Now when call I `Q.all(arr)` and return the object value in `then()`, nothing's happen and still my array contains promise objects. Is there any way to work with the `Q.all()` and such a complex arrays?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's how Q is supposed to work.
To get all the values, not the promises, you may use `.spread()`:

```
Q.all([a, b]).spread(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
```

Each argument of the `spread()` callback will be the result of each promise, in its order.

If you think you'll have lots of promises in such array, loop thru the argument provided in `then()` and replace the promises with its value:

```
Q.all(promises).then(function(result) {
    for (var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (Q.isPromise(result[i])) {
            result[i] = result[i].valueOf();
        }
    }

    // Next step!
});
```

Comment: if you like to use the `.spread()` and don't have a fix size of the array of promisses, you can get the values of all the promises from the `arguments` property, inside the success function of `.spread()`. All node.js function has an arguments object inside them, and this object has all paramters passed to this function on current invokation.