# How can a service return data and multiple promises to a controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have defined a service with functions like this:

```
angular.module('common').factory('_o', ['$angularCacheFactory', '$http', '$q', '$resource', '$timeout', '_u',

   function ($angularCacheFactory, $http, $q, $resource, $timeout, _u) {      

       var _getContentTypes = function ($scope) {
           var defer = $q.defer();
           $http.get('/api/ContentType/GetSelect', { cache: _u.oyc })
               .success(function (data) {
                   $scope.option.contentTypes = data;
                   $scope.option.contentTypesPlus = [{ id: 0, name: '*' }].concat(data);
                   $scope.option.sContentType = parseInt(_u.oyc.get('sContentType')) || 0;
                   defer.resolve();
               })
           return defer.promise;
       };

         return {
           getContentTypes: _getContentTypes
       }

   }]);
```

I am calling this in my controller like this:

```
.controller('AdminProblemController', ['$http', '$q', '$resource', '$rootScope', '$scope', '_g', '_o', '_u',
 function ($http, $q, $resource, $rootScope, $scope, _g, _o, _u) {

     $scope.entityType = "Problem";
     _u.oyc.put('adminPage', $scope.entityType.toLowerCase());

     $q.all([
        _o.getContentTypes($scope),
        _o.getABC($scope),
        _o.getDEF($scope)
     ])
```

Am I correct in saying this is not the best way to use a service. I think I should be returning the 
content type data and then in the controller assigning to the scope not in the service.

But I am not sure how to do this as my service just returns a defer.promise and I am using $q.all so I think I should populate the scope after $q.all has returned success for every call.

Can someone give me some advice on how I should return data from a service with a promise and have it populate the $scope after $q.all has completed with all calls successful ?

Comment: you're right, this is a very bad way of using service... to do what you want, you should return promise in each method and then you can chain them and do something at the end, you just have to figure how to pass data so they are all available in the ending promise

Comment: btw. `$http.get` returns a promise already, so you don't have to wrap it inside another promise... And there was a great article about promises in this week's javascript weekly, you will find a `chain` pattern there - http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely correct in saying that the controller should really be doing this, it would be much cleaner to remove the passing around of your scope (and make it more re-usable). I don't know your exact use case and it is a little confusing to read, but you can do this by hooking into the promises that are created by `$http`, as well as still handling when all of the promises have been completed.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PtM8N/3/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    {{model | json}}
    <div ng-show="loading">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.service("_service", ["$http", function (http) {
    this.firstRequest = function () {
        return http.get("http://json.ph/json?delay=1000")
        .then(function (res) {
            // manipulate data
            res.data.something = new Date();
            return res.data;
        });
    };
    this.secondRequest = function () {
        return http.get("http://json.ph/json?delay=2000")
        .then(function (res) {
            // manipulate data
            res.data.something = 12345;
            return res.data;
        });
    };
    this.thirdRequest = function () {
        return http.get("http://json.ph/json?delay=3000")
        .then(function (res) {
            // manipulate data
            res.data.something = "bacon";
            return res.data;
        });
    };
}]);

app.controller("Ctrl", ["$scope", "_service", "$q", function (scope, service, q) {

    scope.loading = true;
    scope.model = {};

    var firstRequest = service.firstRequest();
    var secondRequest = service.secondRequest();
    var thirdRequest = service.thirdRequest();

    q.all([firstRequest, secondRequest, thirdRequest]).then(function (responses) {
        scope.model.first = responses[0];
        scope.model.second = responses[1];
        scope.model.third = responses[2];
        scope.loading = false;
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Dan, Thanks for your help / advice. However what I am looking for is to only populate the scope if all of the promises have succeeded. Looking at your code I think it will populate the scope if just one of the three requests is completed. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153410/how-to-use-q-all-with-complex-array-of-promises

Comment: You don't have to use the data straight away, wrapped in an `ng-if` or not even put into the scope at all. However, what you want should just be a slight tweak, 2s.

Comment: Updated to do exactly what my example was doing, however populating all at once when all 3 are finished.

Comment: Dan, Can you confirm that this will work okay if for example one of those http calls fails. I just realized my solution uses var defer = $q.defer(); but that's not something you use.

Comment: If one of the http requests fails, the `.all()` should fire the failure handler: http://jsfiddle.net/PtM8N/4/ Updated the fiddle slightly to show that. If you want more control, you can always also use your `q.defer()` method combined with this. Basically returning `deferred.promise` and `http.get()` is the same thing, they are both promises, can both be passed to `q.all()` and both have `.then` handlers etc. Think the only difference is that a custom promise won't have `.success`.

Comment: Does this not answer your issue?